# How to protect specific data in Hadoop

Tags: security, hadoop, hbase

We stored all our customers data in hadoop. We do have some specific security policies we'd like to be enforced. e.g. there is a customers HBase table, it stores all our customers' information. There are some VIP customers can't be exposed directly without specific authorisation. For example, only the CEO, CTO or CIO has the authorisation to view the VIP customers' info.

For now, we are thinking about to leave all the raw data stored in HBase, which is the single point of the truth, and filter out the VIP customers at the application level. Normally, This is what we do if it's a RDBMS under the hood.

Just wondering is there any experiences or best practices for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You now have quite a few good options if **HBase** is your target implementation technology. At the fine grained **technology** level, you could apply [cell level security](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/hbase_cell_security), similar to how accumulo does it.

For example, here is excerpt from a [blog](https://communities.intel.com/community/itpeernetwork/datastack/blog/2013/10/29/hbase-cell-security) describing how to set ACLs for the users or a group for a particular 'cell' (intersection of a row and a column):

> When storing or mutating a cell, the HBase user can now add ACLs, using a backwards compatible extension to the HBase API.
>
> `Mutation#setACL(String user, Permission perms);`
>
> Like at the table or
>   column family level, a subject is granted permissions to the cell. Any
>   number of permissions for any number of users (or groups using @group
>   notation) can be added.

Here is an excellent [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/HBaseCon/features-session-2) on this subject as well.

Beyond, you could look into [Knox](http://knox.apache.org/), [Rhino](https://github.com/intel-hadoop/project-rhino/) and perhaps [Sentry](https://sentry.incubator.apache.org/) (incubating) if you are interested in higher level/row level open source security frameworks for Hadoop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Edmon, I am aware of the existence of Knox, Rhino, Sentry, But in my case, the policy is more like row level security: "select * where from customers where customer_id is NOT VIP". My question is more about, like this kinda of policies, if we want to control it as the source level(hadoop), what's the best practice.

Comment: @Shengjie - in that case, I think cell level security, for HBase, is exactly what you need. It gives you an ultra fine-grain control over who (role/user) can access what unit of data. It is called cell level security because as we know HBase is not really a relational database, but the effect is the same as row/column level security.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe you can have a separate database (or table) for the VIPs' information. Then you only need to deploy user authentication for each database.